# Visualizing Large Object Heap Fragmentation

Tags: .net, performance, memory, large-object-heap

Is there any tool out there to visualize large object heap?

Currently I'm using ANTS Memory Profiler, it tells that LOH is fragmented but you can't actually see the fragmentation (I'm hoping to see a visual representation of LOH like Windows Defrag tool visualize disk fragmentation).

Comment: The LOH is always fragmented.  Knowing what was in the holes requires a time machine.  There are a few degenerate cases, but if you are trying to fix a problem with a program that allocates more than a gigabyte of its virtual address space then you need to switch to a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: @Hans I'm not after what *was* in LOH, I'm after what blocks are filled right now which makes the fragmentation obvious (assuming one knows what will go into LOH). And it doesn't really require time machine many memory profilers store this kind of history for stuff like disposed items, in theory they can support this as well.

Comment: ClrProfiler isn't able to show memory from process dump :(

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft CLR Profiler tool will be able to show you a visual graph of the large object heap.

How To: Use CLR Profiler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

Identify And Prevent Memory Leaks In Managed Code - Look at the section on "Leaking" Managed Heap Memory

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx#S5